# White labeling the product

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.5

I have visual studio solution with 2 projects - ImageBrowser (win forms) and ImageBrowserInstaller (WiX). 
Assuming that it's a not stand alone product but meant to be enterprise and client that
acquires it want it to have certain name, for instance Picture Viewer. That means that the product folder name will change, programs and features entry and so on.

Is there any friendly way to do so? some delimiter that i put in XML that value i can provide during compilation? or I will have to have set of projects for this need?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the [Application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ad7d6w76%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before compilation.